# How to use android-filechooser library?

Tags: android, filechooser

How to use https://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/ ? I can't see any docs or examples, although the library looks quite mature and usable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you **should purchase** [in here](http://www.haibison.com/libs/android-filechooser) to use that library.

> Developer Book
>
> It's a PDF file. There are 3 licenses available:

```
Developer Book +, at $9.99 -- for single developer.
Developer Book 2+, at $49.99 -- up to 10 developers.
Developer Book 3+, at $299 -- for your entire company.
```

> It's about:

```
Integrating the library into your projects using Eclipse IDE.
Basic guide to build custom file providers. Saying, this is a basic guide and might not fit your needs.
```

That library really is beautifull,

but there always are the other libraries have beautifull too, such as [this](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser).

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. So much for open-source.
I have spent the last 3 hours studying `aFileChooser`, there are a few things that I don't understand about it. Have you used it?

Comment: P. S. What I figure out how to use `android-filechooser` on my own, without purchasing the guide? The license doesn't seem to prohibit it...

Comment: Yes, I already used it. What's wrong with u guy? Please tell me. p/s: Yes, I see.

Comment: The library source code seems well documented. For a simple file choosing that would be enough.